# Javascript default parameter

Tags: javascript

I was reading the Three.js code when a silly question arose: Is there any difference between the codes below?

```
frameHeight = frameHeight !== undefined ? frameHeight : 24;
```

and

```
frameHeight = frameHeight || 24;
```

(frameHeight is a parameter of the function)

Thanks

Comment: Not a javascript expert, but I believe the first will only return 24 if `frameHeight` is `undefined` where as the second will return 24 if `frameHeight` has any "falsey" value, like `null`, `''`, etc.

Comment: They are different, but `if(frameHeight===undefined)frameHeight=24;` IS equivalent but it is more readable and performs better since its value will only change when needed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, they are different.

```
frameHeight = frameHeight || 24;
```

This will coerce `frameHeight` to a boolean value. If it is `0`, `''`, `false`, `null`, `undefined`, or `NaN` it will be false and `frameHeight` will be defaulted to 24.

```
frameHeight = frameHeight !== undefined ? frameHeight : 24;
```

This will explicitly check if `frameHeight` is not `undefined` and ONLY for `undefined` will it default it to `24`.

Answer (score 2):

```
frameHeight = frameHeight || 24;
```

^ Will do a null check as well. Will also do a check for 0, false, empty string ('') NaN and undefined

```
frameHeight = frameHeight !== undefined ? frameHeight : 24;
```

^ Will just check for undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a difference and that difference can be significant depending upon the circumstances.

```
frameHeight = frameHeight || 24
```

will assign `24` to frame if frameHeight is initially ANY falsey value such as `""`, `0`, `null`, `undefined`, `NaN` or `false`.

Whereas:

```
frameHeight = frameHeight !== undefined ? frameheight : 24
```

will only assign it `24` if the initial value is exactly `undefined`.

So, of possible significance in this particular function, the second method will allow you to pass `0` for the `frameHeight` to set a zero height, but the first method will not because it will override that `0` to `24`.

Answer (score 0):

```
frameHeight = frameHeight || 24;
```

fails for `frameHeight` = 0 works for `frameHeight` = null

```
frameHeight = frameHeight !== undefined ? frameHeight : 24;
```

fails for `frameHeight` = null works for `frameHeight` = 0

Comment: It will return 24 in both the cases of null and 0 for frameHeight = frameHeight || 24.

Comment: fails in the sense - In first case if value is 0 it will be reset to 24, but 0 is valid. If value is null it will be reset to 24, because null is invalid value. So fails for 0 works for null.

Comment: In second case, if value is 0 it won't be reset, because 0 is valid. If value is null it won't be reset, but null is invalid value. So works for 0, fails for null.

Comment: In my chrome dev tools when I do this: var a = 0; var c = a || 24. c equals 24.

Comment: Yes, but it is wrong logically because if frameHeight is 0, it should not change it to 24.

Comment: I agree, but because it's short circuited there is no way to check if the value on the other side of the (||) is an integer. JavaScript ain't that smart. We should amend the spec.